# Google Search w/ Chrome Incognito w/ Gnome Do

Tags: linux, google-chrome, gnome-do

I've installed Google Chrome as my default browser in Ubuntu, and recently installed Gnome Do and enabled the Google Search plugin.  The Google Search from Gnome Do works exactly as expected but for one thing: Chrome (which is typically set to open in "incognito" mode) does *not* open in "incognito" mode.  The shortcuts on my desktop, taskbar, and menus all have the `--incognito` flag attached (which works just fine), but the browser refuses to open in this mode when launched from Gnome Do.  Any suggestions?

Also, please note the settings for the Google Search plugin in Gnome Do:

[image]

It's obvious that Gnome Do just passes the Google Search blindly to the default browser.  In other words, there are no configurable settings specifically for Chrome.  Any thoughts?

Comment: UPDATE: I figured out a partial solution.  If I already have an incognito window open, a Google Search from Gnome Do will open the search in a new tab of the incognito window.  It isn't a perfect solution, but I'll take it if no one else comes up with a better idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to System -> Preferences -> Preferred Applications

The first tab, "Internet", includes "Web Browser". Choose "Custom" (the last item). You will then be able to type in the "Command:" text box. Put in

```
chromium-browser --incognito %s
```

Comment: Perfect!  Worked like a charm!  You, my friend, are a genius.